# What is chronological order of all events or big events that have ever happened in Puranas

Tags: puranas, avatars, kalpa, manvantara, sati

According to ch 19 of prabhas kand of skand puran **we are in 31st kalpa of second phase Brahma** and previous kalpa was pitr kalpa.
But other Puranas say we are in 1st kalpa of second phase of Brahma. And previous kalpa was Padma kalpa.
***What is the truth present kalpa is 1st or 31st and what was previous kalpa padma kalpa or pitr kalpa?***
[image: Family tree]

According to this family tree ram and krishna are in this tree it means that it is family tree of our kalpa.And according to this family tree sati is daughter of Daksha.It means sati was in this kalpa. But according to skand puran sati was born in 1st manvantara of pitr kalpa which was previous kalpa. And Parvati born in end of 6th manvantara of present kalpa. And age of parvat(incarnation of shakti) is 6 months of Brahma it means that events of a kalpa does not repeat in another kalpa.
**So I am very confused . Can you clear it?**
I also wants to know when was tarkasur born. Because he was present in time of sat and parvat both. Who was father of tarkasur.
And I also wants to know when in which kalpa and which manvantara Mahishasura , Shumbha and Nishumbh were present.

***Can you please make a list of major events of Puranas (including answer if questions that I have asked above) in the list of chronological list.***

Comment: Hello! Welcome to HSE. Please take a tour of this website and visit the help center to get acquainted and read the guidelines for asking questions and answering them. As your question is currently written, it may get a close vote for being too broad. Also, some of your queries are already discussed here so it may also get a close vote for duplicate. Kindly edit it if you wish. Have a good day!

Comment: Like most folks trying to understand this stuffs, I’ve of course also found lots of contradictory numbers w/ the yug, chaturyug and kalp calculations. Different people have different ideas of how long is a chaturyug and such. You might get contradicting answers here on this. Maybe we are getting bogged down in details who knows ? But I don’t get it either ! Haha:D 

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.